# Internationalization and parameterized queries

Tags: c#, internationalization, datatable, dataset

I make a DataSet and DataTable in C#
and then make a report for a SQL Server DB (I Use Report Viewer).
I need to search Value field in DataBase
when my Value is English Like "test" every thing is be OK,
but when my value is Arabic\Persian\Farsi the report viewer dosen't show me anything.

My query is this:

```
SELECT DetailsProducts.DarSad, Materials.Material, Products.Product
FROM DetailsProducts INNER JOIN
    Materials ON DetailsProducts.MaterialID = Materials.ID INNER JOIN
    Products ON DetailsProducts.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE (Products.Product = @Product)
```

When I need one value I can use this query:

```
SELECT DetailsProducts.DarSad, Materials.Material, Products.Product
FROM DetailsProducts INNER JOIN
    Materials ON DetailsProducts.MaterialID = Materials.ID INNER JOIN
    Products ON DetailsProducts.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE (Products.Product =N'بطری') //(Bottle = بطری)
```

It is OK, but this " N'exp' " dose not work when I Use Parameters. How can I fix this?

Comment: is the DB/column UTF8 ? what type is `@Product` ? what is the used connection string ? what version of SQL Server is this ?

Comment: @Product is string\NvarChar and string connection = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\KianiWorkShopDB\\Kiani.mdf;User Instance=True;Integrated Security=True;"; my verison SQL Server is 2008 , about your first qusetion I Control it and tell you

Comment: MS SQL Server  supports UTF-8 by default when you create a new database. You can use nvarchar data type to store unicode data.          http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/73e930a8-ed50-486d-b5c1-604443f8365f

Comment: I know that it supports UTF8 but depending on the version it has some subtle quirks (a bit less with V 2008)... with you described the answer below should work... did you try it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your parameter with `SqlDbType` equal to `SqlDbType.NVarChar`:

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@Product";
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameter.Value = "بطری";
```